# Can't dynamically place text over the top of polygon

Tags: text, svg

I want to put text on top of my polygons. unfortunately the text goes behind the shape is there anything similar to the css z index?

here is part of the svg in my html (its a lot of code because im drawing a map so here is only a little part of it.) Although below they all have the same coords, I did originally place them over the shape using the inspector in chrome, however the shapes remained above the text.

```
<svg width="400" height="800" viewBox="0 0 400 800" id="svg-doc">

<rect id="central-park" class="shape" x="154" y="370"width="53" height="127" />
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/16">
      <rect id="z10024" class="shape" x="68" y="415" width="85" height="40" />
      <text x="0" y="15" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/17">
      <rect id="z10023" class="shape" x="68" y="457" width="85" height="40"  />
      <text x="0" y="15" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/10">
      <polygon id="z10034" class="shape" points="189,156 137,122 106,121 101,129 99,155 79,155 78,105 94,79 121,67 128,82 163,61 177,62 191,80" />
      <text x="0" y="15" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/28">
        <polygon id="z10040" class="shape" points="188,167 186,155 137,122 108,122 102,126 100,153 77,156 77,166" />
        <text x="0" y="15" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/29">
      <polygon id="z10033" class="shape" points="189,166 187,197 187,203 81,203 77,194 78,166" /> 
      <text x="0" y="15" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>
```

Comment: Hey I added the code, dont think it will be much help though, i was just trying to get a general idea. I couldnt find anything on w3 schools

Answer (score 1):

According to this site: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/an-svg-primer/

> The order in which elements are coded determines their depth order.

In fact, the problem seems to be that all of your text is in the same place, at (0,15) - not underneath the polygons at all?

I edited the code from the question to move the text over the polygons, it is displayed correctly...

```
<svg width="400" height="800" viewBox="0 0 400 800" id="svg-doc">

<rect id="central-park" class="shape" x="154" y="370"width="53" height="127" />
    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/16">
      <rect id="z10024" class="shape" x="68" y="415" width="85" height="40" />
      <text x="70" y="450" fill="#5df8b8">10024</text>
    </a>


    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/17">
      <rect id="z10023" class="shape" x="68" y="457" width="85" height="40"  />
      <text x="70" y="480" fill="#5df8b8">10023</text>
    </a>


    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/10">
      <polygon id="z10034" class="shape" points="189,156 137,122 106,121 101,129 99,155 79,155 78,105 94,79 121,67 128,82 163,61 177,62 191,80" />
      <text x="90" y="110" fill="#5df8b8">10034</text>
    </a>


    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/28">
        <polygon id="z10040" class="shape" points="188,167 186,155 137,122 108,122 102,126 100,153 77,156 77,166" />
        <text x="120" y="160" fill="#5df8b8">10040</text>
    </a>


    <a xlink:href="/zipcodes/29">
      <polygon id="z10033" class="shape" points="189,166 187,197 187,203 81,203 77,194 78,166" /> 
      <text x="120" y="190" fill="#5df8b8">10033</text>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Using the inspector i was moving them accordingly (over the shape) but they were going under neath the shape

Comment: @cdm89 - don't do that then? :) Or change your question to something like "can't dynamically place text over the top of polygon" and include some javascript code which shows the broken example?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, there is no javascript involved here though. im not exactly sure what you mean by dont do that, exactly what else would i do if im not placing the text over the shape using coordinates?

Comment: @cdm89 I mean don't move them using the inspector. It works fine if you specify the coordinates in the html/svg code (or at least, it does for me).

Comment: When I make those changes in my code that does not happen. :(

Comment: @cdm89 what changes? Also, I can move the text around using google chrome element inspector and it doesn't move under the polygon. Maybe something else is going on?